# In Node.JS, by doing require('net'), do you not do require('event')?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code I'm looking at does not have "require('event')" anywhere, and yet I see this code

```
server.on('error', function (e) {
  if (e.code == 'EADDRINUSE') {
    console.log('Address in use, retrying...');
    setTimeout(function () {
      //server.close();
      server.listen(port);//PORT, HOST);
    }, 1000);
  }
  else{ .......
```

That uses "on".

And looking at this line

```
var net = require('net')
```

and this line

```
var server = net.createServer();
```

makes me think that doing require('net') already includes doing require('event').

Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The event register function is already in the `net` module and thats why you are able to listen with `.on` method. Having said that, this does not guarantee that `net` module includes `event` module. It might have its own event methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) makes it quite clear that `net.Server` is an [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter), so `EventEmitter`'s properties and methods (including `.on()`) are inherited.